Jobmanager went down with zero hints
I am having Jobmanager, 3 taskmanager in kubernetes. My jobmanager pod got deleted and new one is created because of HA.
Jobmanager logs has following error
2024-12-25 23:15:30.597 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM. Shutting down as requested.                                
2024-12-25 23:15:30.598 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint down with application status UNKNOWN. Diagnostics Cluster entrypoint has been closed externally..
2024-12-25 23:15:30.600 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                     [] - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:6124                                         
2024-12-25 23:24:06.523 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                
                                            

"2024-12-25 23:15:30.558 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] -  Filter ->  Enricher (15/15) (e93c6ef740fdfec6110cb19d481ee024_20ba6b65f97481d5570070de90e4e791_14_1402) switched from RUNNING to FAILED on 10.68.16.178:44289-456e59 @ 10-68-16-178.taskmanager.XXX.cluster.local (dataPort=33765).
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkExpectedException: The TaskExecutor is shutting down.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor.onStop(TaskExecutor.java:481) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.RpcEndpoint.internalCallOnStop(RpcEndpoint.java:239) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor$StartedState.lambda$terminate$0(PekkoRpcActor.java:574) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor$StartedState.terminate(PekkoRpcActor.java:573) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleControlMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:196) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29) ~[flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253) [flink-rpc-akka57720e69-cbc8-4797-8e9b-5435b16856fc.jar:1.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) [?:1.8.0_432]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) [?:1.8.0_432]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) [?:1.8.0_432]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) [?:1.8.0_432]"


Not getting any hint why job manager went down.
Any help would really be appreciated.
